# Altium compiler gives error on old designator

Tags: altium, compiler

Whenever I change a designator in the schematics, the old designator will be placed in grey between parenthesis behind the new one.
For some sort of reason Altium decided to give errors on the old designators in combination with the new ones. See pictures below for clarity:

[image: Part with designator U4]
[image: Part with old designator U4]
[image: Altium compile error]

I've tried resetting all designators and annotating them again. Closing the application. Thus far only replacing the part with a new one seems to work. But that isn't doable for a full project.

The when I try to reset duplicate designators I get the following message:
[image]

Has anyone had this problem before or does anyone know what might cause (and solve) this problem?

Comment: If you see the old grey designation, it usually means you need to re-compile your project. If you don't like them, then you should be able to permanently turn them off: Preferences -> Schematic -> Compiler -> Compiled Names Expansion, then uncheck "Designators".

Answer (score 1):

There seemed to be a problem in de .Annotation file. I removed the file "ProjectName.Annotation" from the project folder and the compile errors were gone.